# How to rewrite code without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am totaly lost now. I upload my whole code. Is someone could help me I will appreciate it so much!! How can I change it to do not use jQuery, only javaScript?

```
 var CARDS_NUM = 20;    // number of cards in total
var ROW = 5;    //number of cards in rows
var cards = [];
var takenCards = [];
var availableCards= true;   //cards which are available to choose
var attemptsNumber = 0;     //number of moves
var pairs= 0;       //number of guessed pairs of cards
var cadsImages = [
'duck.PNG',
'elephant.png',
'monkey.png',
'pig.png',
'pinguin.png',
'cow.png',
'sheep.png',
'zebra.png',
'lion.png',
'horse.png'
 ];

function startGame() {
cards = [];
takenCards = [];
availableCards = true;
attemptsNumber = 0;
pairs = 0;

var board = $('.board').empty();

for (var i=0; i<CARDS_NUM; i++) {
    cards.push(Math.floor(i/2));
}
```

There is a part which you were suggest me:
    for (i=CARDS_NUM-1; i>0; i--) {
        var swap = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
        var tmp = cards[i];
        cards[i] = cards[swap];
        cards[swap] = tmp;
    }

```
for (var i = 0; i < CARDS_NUM; i++) {

var tile = document.createElement('card');

tile.className = 'card';
tile.setAttribute('data-cardType', cards[i]);
tile.setAttribute('data-index', i);

var current_width = tile.style.width,
    current_height = tile.style.height;

tile.style.left = 5 + (current_width + 5) * (i % ROW);
tile.style.top = 5 + (current_height + 5) * (Math.floor(i / ROW));

board.appendChild(tile);

}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

cardClick(target);
});
```

end of it.

```
function cardClick(element) {
if (availableCards) {
    //if none element is taken
    //or if element's index is not in taken cards
    if (!takenCards[0] || (takenCards[0].data('index') != element.data('index'))) {
        takenCards.push(element);
        element.css({'background-image' :      'url('+cadsImages[element.data('cardType')]+')'})    
    }

    if (takenCards.length == 2) {
        takenCards = false;
        if (takenCards[0].data('cardType') == takenCards[1].data('cardType')) {
            setTimeout('deleteCards()', 500);
        } else {
            setTimeout('resetCards()', 500);
        }

        attemptsNumber++;
        $('.cards').html(attemptsNumber)
    }
}
}

 function deleteCards() {
takenCards[0].fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
takenCards[1].fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();

    pairs++;
    if (pairs >= CARDS_NUM / 2) {
        alert('gameOver!');
    }
    availableCards = true;
    takenCards = new Array();
});
}

function resetCards() {
takenCards[0].css({'background-image':'url(title.png)'})
takenCards[1].css({'background-image':'url(title.png)'})
takenCards = new Array();
availableCards = true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.start_game').click(function() {
    startGame();
});

 })
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript please be careful when you add the tags in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To create and append an element, you would use:

```
var tile = document.createElement("div");
tile.className = "card";
board.appendChild(tile);
```

If you want to use jQuery like `.data()`, you can coin a unique ID and then use that as a key into a JS object that serves as your storage repository (this is basically how jQuery does it):

```
// globally accessible (perhaps in a namespace object
function getUniqueId() {
    return getUniqueId.cntr++;
}
getUniqueId.cntr = 0;

// repository for card data
var cardData = {};

function setCardData(obj, key, data) {
    if (!obj.id) {
        obj.id = getUniqueId();
    }
    if (!(obj.id in cardData)) {
        cardData[obj.id] = {};
    }
    cardData[obj.id][key] = data;
}

function getCardData(obj, key) {
    var itemData = cardData[obj.id];
    if (!itemData) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return itemData[key];
}

for (i=0; i<CARDS_NUM; i++) {
    var tile = document.createElement("div");
    tile.className = "card";
    tile.id = "id_" + getUniqueId();
    board.appendChild(tile);
    setCardData(tile, 'cardType', cards[i]);
    setCardData(tile, 'index', i);
}
```

Since you weren't using the `.id` property, that's what I used here, but you could also use a custom property if you wanted the solution to be totally generic.  If this were a reusable library, you might also hide part of the implementation in a private scope so only the function access was available.  This is to give you a general idea for an implementation and leave those sorts of details to you.

---

You can use `addEventListener()` to register your click event handler.

---

Simulating jQuery's .css, .height, .width involve using `getComputedStyle()` to read CSS properties and then setting style.prop values on the object.

---

You can use the `.innerHTML` DOM property instead of `.html()`.

Comment: I would privatize all the data so you cannot just do `cardData[foo]`

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.getElementsByClassName('card')` and then you can create a "data-like" object:

```
var cardData = {};
```

And then store everything in `cardData`

Etcetera.

---

In your case you *could* do something like this:

```
var dataObjects = (function () {
     var data = {};
     return {
         get: function(id, name) {
             if(!(id in data)) {
                 data.id = {};
             }
             if(name in data.id){
                 return data.id[name];
             }
             else {
                 return false;
             }
         },
         set: function(id, name, value) {
             if(!(id in data)) {
                 data.id = {};
             }
             return data.id[name] = value;
         }
     };
})();
function createCard(index) {
   var tile= document.createElement("div");
   tile.id = "tile_" + index;
   tile.className = "card";
   return card;
}

for (i=0; i<CARDS_NUM; i++) {
    var card = createCard(i);
    dataObjects.set(card.id, 'cardType', cards[i]);
    dataObjects.set(card.id, 'index', i);
    board.appendChild(card);
    // ... 
}
```

Then use `addEventListener` for events and `.style` to change css.
And `.innerHTML` to change HTML content

Comment: Aparently he is creating elements in his code, not selecting existing ones by class.

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn Ahhh true.